# Upgrading .NET Framework from 4.5 to 4.6 using powershell

Tags: asp.net, .net, powershell

We are setting up continuous deployment on our servers and we want it so we have to do as little server customization as possible, so that the powershell script that runs will install everything necessary for a project.  So we have a .NET Framework 4.6.1 project but the server only has .NET Framework 4.5 in the Role and Features.

I typically use this to enable all the required stuff:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIFilter -NoRestart
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIExtensions -NoRestart
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45 -NoRestart
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibility45 -NoRestart
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45 -NoRestart
```

How can I install, upgrade or update .NET Framework to be 4.6+ using powershell?  I don't see any WindowsOptionalFeatures and everything I find online involves actually downloading things and installing them, not via powershell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each OS version brings a different version of [preinstalled .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/get-started/system-requirements#supported-server-operating-systems). The preinstalled version can be activated with the `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature` cmdlet. The newer versions needs to be installed separately either with the setup itself

```
<.NET Framework redistributable> /q /norestart
```

or some software distribution system. If you want to use Powershell you could take a look at Oneget/Chocolatey as software distribution system.

```
Install-Package -Name Dotnet4.6.1
```

Comment: So if we wanted to do it without having the exe, but rather pull it from online, could we use the link given by microsoft to download the .NET 4.6.2 exe: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=780596 /q /norestart

Comment: @Samir, please follow this link for PowerShell help with downloading a file: [link](https://blog.jourdant.me/post/3-ways-to-download-files-with-powershell)

Answer (score 3):

@OlafReitz is 100% right, As MS continues to release versions you need to pull down the files and install them from a redistributable (or use a separate software distribution system), I've created a PowerShell script that does just that in a automated way, I then worked it into my CD pipeline:

```
try {
    #Currently I have this pointed at .NET 4.7.2
    $dotNetURL = "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=863262"

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $dotNetURL -OutFile LatestVersionOfDotNet.exe
    ./LatestVersionOfDotNet.exe /quiet /norestart
}
catch {
    Write-Output $_.Exception.Message
}
```